# How do I keep a textarea equal height with inputs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I keep the top of the message (`textarea`) input inline with the name input and the bottom inline with the phone input?

**I want the message textarea the same height as the 3 inputs on the left combined. I really would like the borders to line up nicely**

I've tried manually specifying the height, but as soon as the window size changes, the height changes, throwing off the design.

How do I accomplish this while still having it responsive?

[image]

To see the results like in the picture, you have to expand the viewable area (due to bootstrap `md`) Here is an external link. https://jsfiddle.net/6ma7ndmL/3/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100,300,400,500,700');
 section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4em 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section .container,
  section .row {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
header.section-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 3em;
}
header.section-header h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
section.contact form {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  color: #000;
}
section.contact form input,
section.contact form textarea {
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: 0.4s border-color ease;
}
section.contact form input:focus,
section.contact form textarea:focus {
  transition: 0.4s border-color ease;
  border-color: #f33;
}
section.contact form textarea {
  resize: none;
}
section.contact form button.btn {
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  float: right;
  transition: 0.4s background-color ease, 0.4s color ease, 0.4s border-color ease;
}
section.contact form button.btn:hover {
  transition: 0.4s background-color ease, 0.4s color ease, 0.4s border-color ease;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #f33;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section.contact form [class^='col-']:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  section.contact form [class^='col-']:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  section.contact form [class^='col-']:nth-child(3) {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="contact">
  <section class="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <header class="section-header">
          <h2>contact</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
                <label for="name">name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
                <label for="email">email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" />
                <label for="phone">phone</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <label for="message">message</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <button id="formsubmit" type="submit" class="btn">send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work. [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/eqcxdebd/) **Edit:** if I understand you correctly you want this code.

```
section.contact form textarea {
    line-height: 98.5px !important;
}
```

98.5px to be exacto mundo :)
Or you can use some javascript and use something like this.

```
document.getElementById("message").rows = "10";
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes it the height of 1 input, I want it the height of all three combined, should have been a little clearer. Thanks anyway

Comment: Check update. I think I am understanding it correctly now?

Comment: Yep, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No worries. Is that what you were looking for mate?

Comment: Sort of, it's close, and I'm able to do the same with `height: 200px` but, I really the want to bottom border to line up (exactly would be nice) with the bottom border of the phone input.

Comment: lol no worries, than to be exact it is yes, 98.5 pixels. Check demo :)

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/8lGTtDHFf.png

This works (mostly), but when I change the view from md to lg, the heights change. Could this be done by setting the `col-md-6` explicitly and then vertically aligning each of the inputs, if so how would I go about this?

Comment: Interesting. I am on chrome and no matter what res, it keeps the height matched perfectly.

Comment: I'm using chrome too, it changes if you zoom the page in or out, 90% seems to mess it up

Comment: With zoom I do not think any method will work spot on. The closest you can get is in the pixel or something like this using JS.. check update.

Comment: The `line-height` seem to be messing up actual text input. http://pasteboard.co/8mnlxrPot.png